# how to put one string in three strings in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/vdpr6gsu/1/

i want to put three parts of the string in three different labels

jquery

```
 var part = "AAAAA\r\n\r\nBBBBB\r\n\r\nCCCCC\r\n\r\n";    
    var part1 = part.substring(0, part.indexOf("\r\n\r\n"));
    var part2 = part.substring(part.indexOf(part1 + '\r\n\r\n'), part.indexOf("\r\n\r\n"));
    var part3 = part.substring(0, part.indexOf("\r\n\r\n") + 2);


    $('#part1').text(part1);
```

HTML

```
allparts


<label id=part1/>
<label id=part2/>
<label id=part2/>
```

not able to show them up  .
how to do that . the three parts in the string are dynamic and their length is not same always  . only thing is that they will have \r\n\r\n as a seperator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Ids should be wrapped in quotes and should be unique

```
<label id="part1"/>
<label id="part2"/>
<label id="part3"/>
<label id="part4"/>
```

And here is a working example

https://jsfiddle.net/vdpr6gsu/9/

```
 const str = 'AAAAA\r\n\r\nBBBBB\r\n\r\nCCCCC\r\n\r\n';    
 const parts = str.split('\r\n\r\n')
 $(".part").each(function (index) {
  $(this).text(parts[index])
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not forget basics of JS when You use jQuery.

```
var part1 = 'op first string';
var part2 = 'and another string';
var joinedString = part1 + part2;

// and now it is ready to use as one string even in jQuery
$('#part1').text(joinedString);
```

Updated https://jsfiddle.net/vdpr6gsu/5/

Answer (score 0):

You can use split for that:

```
var parts = part.split("\r\n").filter(s=>s!=="")
```

Then use any part you want:

```
var p1 = parts[0];
var p2 = parts[1];
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Label is not a Self-Closing tag, you need to change it over to `<label id=part1></label>`

> Self Closing tags reject use of jQuery's `.text()` and `.html()`.

And yes you can use the split method as Soshin mentioned.
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vdpr6gsu/7/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var part = "AAAAA\r\n\r\nBBBBB\r\n\r\nCCCCC\r\n\r\n";    
    var parts = part.split("\r\n").filter(s=>s!=="")
    $('#part1').text(parts[0]);
    $('#part2').text(parts[1]);
    $('#part3').text(parts[2]);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
allparts

<br>
<label id=part1></label>
<br>
<label id=part2></label>
<br>
<label id=part3></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string into array, remove any empty values then iterate that array and use indexing to match elements

```js
var part = "AAAAA\r\n\r\nBBBBB\r\n\r\nCCCCC\r\n\r\n",    
    $partEls = $('.part');

part.split('\n')
    .filter(str =>str.trim())
    .forEach((txt,i) => $partEls.eq(i).text(txt.trim()) )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="part" id="part1"></div>
<div class="part" id="part2"></div>
<div class="part" id="part3"></div>
<div class="part" id="part4"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<label id="part1"></label>
<label id="part2"></label>
<label id="part3"></label>
```

Javascript

```
var str = "AAAAA\r\n\r\nBBBBB\r\n\r\nCCCCC\r\n\r\n";
var parts = str.split("\r\n\r\n");

var max_part = 3; //Number of parts you want to show
for(var index=0; index <= max_part; index++){
    $('#part' + (index+1)).text(parts[index]);
}
```